How to copy texts with colors (as HTML/RTF) from the Run panel on Android Studio
Once you run (usually shift+F10) a project, Android Studio outputs some texts and also the results of print() functions in the Run console with colors like this:

I would like to copy the output of Run with colors to insert them in ex. MS Word. So how to copy as HTML or RTF?
I tried to find anything like "copy as HTML/RTF" in the menu and also searched on the Internet, but couldn't find any clues or any similar questions/posts.
